# strapi on docker with postgres issue

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, strapi

I have followed this [post](https://blog.dehlin.dev/docker-with-strapi-v4) to install strapi version 4 using docker compose, and use it to run a postgres db and a local instance.

When I run:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

This runs strapi and postgres in their own containers

When I run:

```
docker-compose up -d postgresdb && yarn develop
```

I get a error saying that:

> debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.

> error: The server does not support SSL connections

I have enclosed a screenshot of the commands I am running:

[image]

Is there something in either .env, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml or the database.js file settings from the above mentioned tutorial page that is not correct?